# web api authentication in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm confused on how the Web API implements the authentication?

I have gone through the links 1.

1. [Link1](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1223/secure-aspnet-web-api-using-tokens-owin-angularjs)
2. [Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

and need to summarize what I understood.

1. Owin katana is a mechanism that can be implemented for authorization.
2. There will be Iprincipal which can be created either in the host or
   in the httpmodule which will be attached to the currentthread to
       validate.
3. Token based authentication implements owin.

I have very little idea about the authentication mechanism in web api. If someone can help me to understand this, It would be great.

I have the following doubts.

1. Owin is a new way of authentication in MVC? or its already exists as
   a part of windows and form based authentication?
2. If I wrote a module to authenticate what are the different ways I can use to authenticate an api method/controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question could be quite big, I will try to give you some guidelines:

Katana is Microsoft's implementation of the OWIN standard

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana

Token based authorization is supported by OWIN and , therefore, by Katana.
There are two very usual ways to implement this token authorization, you can use Windows Authorization

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana

or you can use a more standard and recommendable way using OAuth:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

With ASP.net (netfx, not core), you use attributes on controller level to provide the metadata necessary to implement the authorization and authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Form authentication is fall under token based authentication in Web API?

Comment: When using OAuth, the Authentication on the form is managed by the Authentication Server. This server, once the client is succesfully identified, send the client a token. The client send the token to your API and the API has to validate it. With ASP.net you merely need to apply some attributes to the Controllers to configure the authentication (the claims)

Comment: Here you can find some additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516747/authenticating-a-net-mvc-application-with-a-web-api?rq=1